# Armazenar resultado da consulta em uma session com PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sql-insert

Tenho um `SELECT` que gera resultados normalmente, porém quando preciso pegar o valor de alguma coluna para usar em uma outra página ele não funciona.

Código da consulta e da tentativa de passar o resultado de uma coluna para uma session:

```
$login = $conexao->prepare("SELECT pessoa.id_login, pessoa.nome 'pnome',
pessoa.id_funcao, pessoa.id_pessoa 'idP', funcao.funcao
FROM login as login
JOIN pessoa as pessoa
on login.id_login = pessoa.id_login 
OIN funcao as funcao 
on pessoa.id_funcao = funcao.id_funcao 
WHERE login.login= :user AND login.senha=:passwd LIMIT 1"); 

$login->bindParam(":user",$user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$login->bindParam(":passwd",$passwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$login->execute();


if($login->rowCount()==1){
   $login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   $this->setLogado($logado=true);

   echo $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
   echo "<br>".$_SESSION['passwd'] = $passwd;
   echo "<br>".$_SESSION['id_pessoa'] = $login->id_pessoa;
   echo "<br>".$_SESSION['abc'] = $login->pnome;
```

Erro que o PHP retorna:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWNkr.png]

Note que as SESSIONS que tiveram o valor atribuído pelas variáveis `$user` e `$passwd` funcionam normalmente.

Comment: se você atribuiu um alias (pessoa.id_pessoa 'idP') você deve usar ele, no caso idP, mas não tenho certeza, acredito que o correto seria (pessoa.id_pessoa as idP)